# how do I generate a custom widget on facebook when people post a link to our site?

Tags: facebook

When you post a youtube link on facebook a player will show up on your wall, letting other people play the video right away. How is this done, and how can you do the same thing for your own website, such that when people post a link to one of your pages, you can make a widget show up on facebook instead of the actual link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It´s actually pretty simple you need to add several meta tags to your website

[Open Graph Protocol](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/)

Something like:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#"
      xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
  <head>
    <title>The Rock (1996)</title>
    <meta property="og:title" content="The Rock"/>
    <meta property="og:type" content="movie"/>
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117500/"/>
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://ia.media-imdb.com/rock.jpg"/>
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="IMDb"/>
    <meta property="fb:admins" content="USER_ID"/>
    <meta property="og:description"
          content="A group of U.S. Marines, under command of
                   a renegade general, take over Alcatraz and
                   threaten San Francisco Bay with biological
                   weapons."/>
    ...
  </head>
  ...
</html>
```

if you want to embedded a video you can just do:

```
<html xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#"> 
    <head>
        ...
        [REQUIRED TAGS]
        <meta property="og:video" content="http://example.com/awesome.swf" />
        <meta property="og:video:height" content="640" />
        <meta property="og:video:width" content="385" />
        <meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash" />
        <meta property="og:video:secure_url" 
              content="https://secure.example.com/awesome.swf" />
        <meta property="og:video" content="http://example.com/html5.mp4" />
        <meta property="og:video:type" content="video/mp4" />
        <meta property="og:video" content="http://example.com/fallback.vid" />
        <meta property="og:video:type" content="text/html" />
        ...
    </head>
</html
```

Comment: yes, but that only displays basic info ... I am talking about serving custom embedded html to facebook when someone shares a link, similar to how youtube video posting works.

Comment: I just edited my answer with the video opengraph, then with those meta tags you can paste the link of your page, and then facebook is going to embedded the video :)