# Facebook: How to create and share to facebook widget, something like a soundcloud widget or youtube player?

Tags: facebook, widget, share

How to create and share to facebook a widget, something  like a soundcloud widget or youtube player?  I mean when you share the soundcloud or youtube widget you can work with it inside of facebook's wallpage. You can use 'play', 'back'  and other buttons of this widget.

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8753888/how-do-i-generate-a-custom-widget-on-facebook-when-people-post-a-link-to-our-sit

Comment: An answer to this question can be found in this post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22751484/how-is-soundcloud-embedding-an-html5-js-widget-on-facebook