# How can I create a widget that can be embed in a Facebook post

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, widget

I want to create a soundcloud like widget that can be embed in a post on Facebook. With my initial research it seems that it is allowed to whitelisted partners only Ref: [How is SoundCloud embedding an HTML5/JS widget on Facebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22751484/how-is-soundcloud-embedding-an-html5-js-widget-on-facebook). The widget will needs to render HTML/CSS/JS only no video streaming/flash/sound buffering required.

I already have an iFrame link to that widget but sharing on Facebook resolves it to a normal link only.

Need help! Thanks :)

Comment: As you already figured out, that functionality is only available to a very limited set of Facebook partners, and AFAIK you can not apply to become one.